# Generate TTF font preview for multiple files

Tags: macos, fonts

I want to generate a preview of multiple TTF fonts without installing them.

Each font should have custom text, and the output should be 1 font per line in a format like JPEG or PDF, so that I could view them all at once.

I am using OS X but if there is a solution under Windows only I would be happy to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ImageMagick, but it doesn't use native text rendering.

`i=1; for f in *.ttf; do convert -size x30 -gravity center -font "$f" -pointsize 16 label:"${f##*/}: some text" font_$((i++)).png; done; convert -append font_*.png fonts.png`

Or if the fonts have been installed, you could use `/Library/Scripts/Font Book/Create Font Sample.scpt` or a shell script like this:

```
preview=$(jot -s '' -c 89 33)

out="<table>
"
IFS=$'\n'
for font in Times Helvetica; do
    out+="<tr style=\"font-family:'$font'\"><td>$font</td><td>$preview</td></tr>
"
done
out+="</table>"

echo "$out" > /tmp/fonts.html
open /tmp/fonts.html
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using PrintMyFonts to keep all my most used fonts listed and displayed in a PDF file.  The font list can also be saved as DOCX, ODT or RTF document. Besides printing all fonts you can also select only single ones and decide freely what is printed in this font: the name of the font, a numbering, a sentence and letters of your choice or everything, together.

You can download a copy of this FREE utility from https://www.sttmedia.com/printmyfonts

I have no affiliation with this utility - I am just recommending one of hundreds of utilities that I have discovered and found useful.

Comment: If this is yours then you need to declare your affiliation in the answer